# using map to create a new plain object in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i am trying to map my conversation array to create a new object with url and thumbnail url instead of the image file name.

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
const conversations = await Conversation.findAll({
  include: [
  //   {
  //   model: Message,
  //   where: {
  //     [Op.or]: [
  //       { senderId: req.user.id }, 
  //       { receiverId: req.user.id },
  //     ],
  //   },
  //   required: true, // RIGHT  JOIN
  // },
  {
    Post,
    attributes:["id","title","userId"],
    include: [
      { model: User, attributes: ["id", "name", "email"] },
    { model: Post_Image, attributes: ["id", "images"] },
    ],
  }
],
});

if (!conversations) return res.status(404).send();

const baseUrl = config.get("assetsBaseUrl");

const plainConversations = conversations.map(x=>x.get({ plain: true }));
const resultPosts = [];
for (const post of plainConversations) {
  const { Post_Images, ...postAttributes } = post;
  const IMAGES = Post_Images.map((postImage) => ({
    url: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_full.jpg`,
    thumbnailUrl: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_thumb.jpg`,
  }));

  resultPosts.push({ ...postAttributes, images: IMAGES });
}
res.send(resultPosts);

});
```

when i try this code i keep getting cannot read property map of undefined.

Comment: The most likely issue is with the following line `const { Post_Images, ...postAttributes } = post;`, could you log the value of `Post_Images`, before the map on the next line?

Comment: @CoryHarper i get undefined

Comment: Right, so what that tells you is that `Post_Images` is not a property on the `post` you are iterating over. Try logging `post` at the same line and see what it looks like.

Comment: {
  id: 1,
  user1: 43,
  user2: 45,
  PostId: 523,
  Post: {
    id: 523,
    title: 'test',
   Post_Images: [ [Object] ]
  }
}

Comment: Change `const { Post_Images, ...postAttributes } = post;` to `const { Post: { Post_Images }, ...postAttributes } = post;`

Comment: I suspect you will have further issues from here, it seems like you are a little confused about the data structure you are working with, but that will get you past the error you are struggling with.

Comment: Thank you @CoryHarper , can you help me clarify what i am confused about? i have used plain objects before in my Post.findAll and it was working but its my first time doing it for MODEL.findAll({include:[model:Post]})

Comment: I'll leave a more detailed full answer.

Comment: Perfect, so i can also accept it as a correct answer rather than just liking the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the fact that you are making a query for `Conversations` and then treating them directly like they are `Posts`. In reality you have queried `Conversations` and then included `Posts` that have a relationship with each `Conversation`, spo they will be present on the returned data, but nested in each object.

```js
// Conversations query
const conversations = await Conversation.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      Post,
      attributes:["id","title","userId"],
      include: [
        { model: User, attributes: ["id", "name", "email"] },
        { model: Post_Image, attributes: ["id", "images"] },
      ],
    }
  ],
});

// Conversations now look something like
{
  ...someValues,
  Post: Post (This is the object that contains the Post_Images) | null;
}[]

...

const plainConversations = conversations.map(x=>x.get({ plain: true }));

// Previously you were referring to the conversations as posts, 
// which was generating confusion
for (conversation of plainConversations) {
  { Post: { Post_Images }, ...ignore } = conversation;
  ...
}
```

I hope this helps you understand what's going on in your code!

Comment: So, my code means for every conversation of plainConversation, for each post ignore the existing postAttributes and replace with the following postAttributes?

Comment: but i have a problem now that my Post attributes such as title is now ignored and replaced with images, how do i fix this issue so i add the new images to the existing post attributes?

Comment: That's why I said you will likely run into more problems in the near future. Your code seems intentioned to modify the `Post_Images` nested within each `Post` which is nested within each `Conversation`. However, that is not currently what it is doing, not properly anyway.

Comment: That's a little out of scope of your original question, I would suggest posting a whole new question to get that answered, if you end up struggling to figure it out.

Comment: I just solved the issue. instead of replacing posts with images, i added images to the array, thanks